# from iframe open link in new window using javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe

I need to open a link using javascript from an iframe into a new window (escape the iframe and open a new window, not the parent window). I've looked at the many similar questions in SO but can't get any of the solutions to work so please don't tag this a duplicate.

I have to use an iframe and js (not an html hyperlink so target="_blank" won't work) so I'm hoping to just modify the code I have to work.

The code I'm using from the iframe is:

```js
window.location.href = '../../page/page2';
```

I've tried

```html
<base target="_blank" /> and <base target="_blank">
```

in the iframe's head but this doesn't effect it. Does anyone know how to mod the code above to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, right after posting this question I came across what seems to be a workable solution. Here's the code that worked for me:

```js
window.open('../../page/page2','_blank');
```